# SQLite referring to a named column from within another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a situation where I'm using a named column as such:

```
SELECT title, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) as nameprefix FROM employees
```

Now the issue is that I'd like to add another named column and somehow refer to `nameprefix` in it. Is this possible? Essentially I would like to do this:

```
SELECT title, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) as nameprefix, 
(CASE WHEN nameprefix = 'Dr' THEN 'FOUND' ELSE 'NOPE' END) as flag 
FROM employees
```

It complains with an error: `Error: no such column: nameprefix`. The actual use-case involves complex sub-queries and I'd like to be able to re-use their results rather than duplicating these sub-queries in each column that requires the result.

Comment: Use a CTE or subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you wish to view the table as if the first two characters of the `title` field are considered a separate, named column.  So, I'd use `CREATE VIEW` to build exactly that view and then query against it, rather than against the underlying table.

So, in your case, issue something like

```
CREATE VIEW EmployeesWithCols (Name, Title, NamePrefix) AS 
   SELECT Name, Title, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) FROM Employee
```

Now, simply replace the table `employee` in your original query with `employeeswithcols` and you will magically have a new `NamePrefix` column available.  Of course, you'll probably need some additional columns in the view as well.

As a side note, I generally name views that are used only to add virtual computed columns to a single table with the table name and prefix "Ex" (as per many internal Windows functions) but in this case and many others that naming convention is ripe for embarrassment if you are not rigorous about the letter case in which you write the view name.

Comment: I think a view in fact might just be what I'm after. I'll explore these now - are these always 'up-to-date', as-in, if data changes in the original table which this view was based on, will querying it always return reliable results?

Comment: Yes, a view is simply a stored query that is evaluated any time it is referred to in another query.  There is no separate storage for the data in the view other than the underlying tables and the contents are, by definition, accurate and up-to-date when read.  If the view definition is "expensive" to evaluate the performance of dependent queries can be affected but in this use case, in which you're using the view to add virtual, inexpensive computed columns to a single table, you should see little or no performance effect.

Comment: Thank you! So I'm now exploring views but I think what I'm trying to do may not be possible. The sub-queries that are being turned into named columns are in fact queries run on the same table in order to extract extra information. An employee can also be a manager of another employee, so to extract this 'parent - child' relationship, I need to perform sub-queries on the same table and extract separate information as individual named columns. This perhaps cannot be turned into a View, at least I don't see how.

Comment: Any query that can be issued can be used to define a view.  However, I think what you want to do is simpler -- think of it as decomposing your problem into two steps.  First, a simple step to transform the columns into the form you need.  Then, use that first, simple view in a query to perform the complex logic.  I'll update the answer. . .

Answer (score 3):

this is possible:

```
select title, nameprefix from 
(
    select title, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) as nameprefix FROM employees
)
where nameprefix = 'Dr'
```

Comment: Won't work - I need to use the named column from within another named column

Comment: this is the only way that i can think of when someone wants to use a named column... i think you should try to conform your query to use these simpler and more readable features... i'm sure if you provide more detail on what you want to do, it'd be better

Answer (score 0):

You can use alias in select  you must  repeat the code

```
 SELECT title, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) as nameprefix, 
 CASE WHEN  SUBSTR(title, 1, 2)= 'Dr' THEN 'FOUND' ELSE 'NOPE' END  as flag 
 FROM employees
```

of use a subselect eg:in join

```
 SELECT title, t.nameprefix , 
 CASE WHEN  nameprefix = 'Dr' THEN 'FOUND' ELSE 'NOPE' END  as flag 
 FROM employees
 JOIN (select id, SUBSTR(title, 1, 2) as nameprefix 
          FROM employees ) t on t.id = employees.id
```

Comment: Yes I'm already doing that, sadly since I'm using complex sub-queries, it ends up re-querying the database multiple times and seems to be a bottleneck

Comment: if you need  you create a view or a subselect table